# Example of a square-integrable function that is not almost surely bounded

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Almost sure boundedness is a strong condition which implies the finiteness of moment at any order. Now let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be square-integrable (w.r.t. Lebesgue measure), i.e., $\int f^2(x) \mathrm d x < \infty$. Could you provide an example of such $f$ that is not almost surely bounded (w.r.t. Lebesgue measure)?

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^{1/4}}\boldsymbol 1_{(0,1]}(x)$.

Comment: @Surb Could you transfer your comment to an answer so that i can accept it?

Comment: Ah!! Surb beat me to it.. I was typing my answer lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$  in $(0,1)$ with the Lebesgue measure is a classic example in showing that $L^{1}$ need not be a subset of $L^{\infty}$ . (in fact $L^{1}$ need not be a subset of $L^{p}$ for any $p>1$.

So just take the square root (i.e. $\frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{4}}})$ and you'll get an $L^{2}$ function that is not $L^{\infty}$